# OrderByDescending not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I'm using EFCore and trying to get entities from the database sorted in DateTime order.
The class looks like this, I googled and saw some other users had problems where they used string as Date but I'm using DateTime both in the DB and in C#.

```
public class MyEntity
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int OwnerId {get;set;}
  public DateTime Modified {get;set;}
}

public IQueryable<MyEntity> Get(Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> expression) => _context.MyEntity.Where(expression);

List<MyEntity> myEntities = Get(x=> x.OwnerId == user.Id).OrderByDescending(x=> x.Modified).ToList();
```

And this is what I get out. The list is kinda in order but...

```
Modified= {1753-01-01 00:00:00} <--- 1753 to 2022-09-13 my first thought here was that maybe there is something special about 1753?
Modified= {2022-09-13 18:46:47} 
Modified= {2022-08-16 11:14:49} 
Modified= {2022-08-02 08:13:16} 
Modified= {2022-08-02 08:21:52} <- wrong time, times just seem to be in random order? My thought here was that perhaps orderbyDescending can't handle times?
Modified= {2022-08-02 08:58:30} 
Modified= {2022-08-02 09:13:07} 
Modified= {2022-08-02 11:15:30} 
Modified= {2022-08-02 11:50:43} 
Modified= {2022-08-01 07:05:52} 
Modified= {2022-08-01 12:52:09} 
Modified= {2022-08-01 13:38:59} 
Modified= {2022-07-20 18:56:32} 
Modified= {2022-07-14 10:53:09} < ... 07-19 to 07-14 to 07-18 Okay, here i'm lost. It's not 1753, it is not a time but a date that got out of order? Why?
Modified= {2022-07-18 15:00:02} 
Modified= {2022-07-17 14:28:52} 
Modified= {2022-07-15 15:13:53} 
Modified= {2022-07-15 15:03:47} 
Modified= {2022-07-15 13:39:31} 
Modified= {2022-07-15 12:37:53} 
Modified= {2022-07-15 13:45:41} 
Modified= {2022-07-15 12:39:37} 
Modified= {2022-04-08 08:05:22} 
Modified= {2022-04-04 08:53:45} 
Modified= {2022-04-04 08:34:12} 
Modified= {2022-04-04 13:19:56} 
Modified= {2022-04-04 14:16:25} 
Modified= {2022-04-04 14:37:36} 
Modified= {2022-04-01 13:48:00} 
Modified= {2022-04-01 12:44:28} 
Modified= {2022-04-01 11:58:12} 
Modified= {2022-03-17 09:22:58}  <--- 03-17 to 03-18 back to 03-17?
Modified= {2022-03-18 10:01:55} 
Modified= {2022-03-17 10:06:29} 
Modified= {2022-03-15 08:50:03} 
Modified= {2022-03-15 11:08:19} 
Modified= {2022-03-14 15:49:48}
```

So what is the secret? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't think of anything that would lead to this result. Could you try and create a [repro]? Perhaps seeding the database with similar data until you get the same outcome.

Comment: What is the data type of the underlying column in SQL?

Comment: What database are you using?  What happens if you order by binary date time? `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Update.ToBinary())`

Comment: Don't know if it's a typo, but shouldn't `Get(x=> x.OwnerId = user.Id)` be `Get(x=> x.OwnerId == user.Id)` (with two equal signs, not one)? I imagine this would cause a compiler error, not a weird run-time issue, but worth checking and correcting your question

Comment: Should be : List<MyEntity> myEntities = Get(......)

Comment: @falowil How about providing [mre]? At minimum, EFC version, db type and provider type & version, and sample data which reproduces the issue.

Comment: @AdamCohen when i .ToBinary() it will generate the error 

Translation of method 'System.DateTime.ToBinary' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Comment: @IvanStoev Do you have any suggestion on the easiest way be to make a new database with sample content available for someone else without hosting it myself?

Comment: @falowil In this particular case you could post a sample `DbContext` class with `DbSet<MyEntity>` and sample data using `.modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasData(...)` calls inside on model creating.

Comment: @falowil try putting ToList before the OrderByDecending (i.e. `Get(x=> x.OwnerId == user.Id).ToList().OrderByDescending(x=> x.Modified.)`) to determine if ordering issue is reproducible/consistent on the client side.  If not, I suspect it's a server side data type issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know without a reproducible example, but I suspect the issue may be caused by (i) navigation properties if they exist on the `MyEntities` object or (ii) a data type issue on the server side. Try the following to debug each case:

**(i) - Navigation Property Troubleshooting**

Try selecting only the columns in the example prior to `OrderByDescending` as follows:

```
    List<MyEntity> myEntities = Get(x => x.OwnerId == user.Id)
        .Select(h => new { h.Id, h.OwnerId, h.Modified})
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Modified)
        .ToList();
```

**(ii) - Server-Side Data Type Troubleshooting**

Try selecting putting `.ToList()` before `.OrderByDescending()` to pull the data down from the database and run the ordering in Linq on the client-side to determine if the behavior is consistent:

```
    var myEntities = Get(x => x.OwnerId == user.Id)
        .Select(h => new { h.Id, h.OwnerId, h.Modified})
        .ToList()
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Modified);
```